# Remove all files in folder except files with certain sequence

Tags: command-line, find

I have a folder with a massive number of .dat files that follows a certain pattern (i.e., `*_t_0.1000.dat, *_t_0.1001.dat .... , *_t_0.2000.dat`). What I eventually want to do is to delete all files except files that ends with the sequence: `*_t_0.1000.dat, *_t_0.1005.dat,*_t_0.1010.dat ... *_t_0.2000.dat`. It is important to mention that the file ends with numbers that have 4 significant digits always. Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ls "*_t_0.1??[12346789].dat"
```

to check, if the filter works, then

```
rm "*_t_0.1??[12346789].dat"
```

if so. Delete "*_t_0.2000.dat" manually, if the rule stops at 2000 but the files don't.

Else replace the 1 with [12] or ? too.

An alternative might be to use 4 commands like this:

```
 ls "xy_t_0."{1001..1096..5}".dat" 
 ls "xy_t_0."{1002..1097..5}".dat" 
 # you get it?
```

Again, replace ls with rm, if the list is ok.

Comment: That worked! thanks a lot.